# Android Realtime mic data to array

Tags: android, real-time

I want to get the data from mic and store it in a byte array for some processing.
I have tried the code given below but it gives errors on recorder.record function.

I have tried a lot of stuff but it was not worth it. Please do help me.

```
    public class AudioRecordThread implements Runnable  {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int bufferLength = 0;
        int bufferSize;
        short[] audioData;
        int bufferReadResult;
        MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.start();

        try {
            int sampleAudioBitRate=44100;
            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioBitRate,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            if (bufferSize <= 2048) {
                bufferLength = 2048;
            } else if (bufferSize <= 4096) {
                bufferLength = 4096;
            }
            AudioRecord audioRecord;

                /* set audio recorder parameters, and start recording */
             audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleAudioBitRate,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferLength);
            audioData = new short[bufferLength];
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            Log.d("My Activity", "audioRecord.startRecording()");

            boolean isAudioRecording = true;
            boolean isRecorderStart=true;
                /* ffmpeg_audio encoding loop */
            while (isAudioRecording) {
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, audioData.length);

                if (bufferReadResult == 1024 && isRecorderStart) {
                    Buffer realAudioData1024 = ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 0, 1024);

                    ***********************************
                    recorder.record(realAudioData1024);
                    ***********************************

                } else if (bufferReadResult == 2048 && isRecorderStart) {
                    Buffer realAudioData2048_1=ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 0, 1024);
                    Buffer realAudioData2048_2=ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 1024, 1024);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            ***********************************
                            recorder.record(realAudioData2048_1);
                            ***********************************

                        } else if (i == 1) {
                            ***********************************
                            recorder.record(realAudioData2048_2);
                            ***********************************


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

                /* encoding finish, release recorder */
            if (audioRecord != null) {
                try {
                    audioRecord.stop();
                    audioRecord.release();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                audioRecord = null;
            }

            if (recorder != null && isRecorderStart) {
                try {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("My Activity", "get audio data failed:"+e.getMessage()+e.getCause()+e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `I have tried a lot of stuff` what exactly did you try? Perhaps we could help you with it.

Comment: @Smittey. Beside that lot of stuff can you please help me to make the above code error free.

Comment: What is the stack trace? There isn't really enough information to go from..